# Classify hex grids with Turf, Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, turfjs

I have a filtered hex grid that I would like to classify.

I created the hex with

```
var hexgrid = turf.hexGrid(bbox, cellWidth, units);
```

I aggregated values with

```
var aggregated = turf.collect(hexgrid, myGeoJson, 'MyValue', 'NewCol');
```

where myGeoJson is a multi-point FeatureCollection and MyValue is a feature property either null or > 0

I filtered the hex with

```
var hexFiltered = L.geoJson(aggregated, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return feature.properties.NewCol.length > 0;
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Each hex object can be accessed with

```
console.log(hexFiltered["_layers"]);

output = Object { 49: Object, 51: Object, 52: Object, 53: Object...
```

Each object then has .feature.properties.NewCol[n]
and each array has the index (0, 1, 2) and value (null, 1 +)

**How can I classify each hex grid with a sum of the array values?**

I have tried this with native javascript but all I can achieve is a string with each value.

```
var counts = {};
for (var obj in hexFiltered["_layers"]) {
    // Output the id of each obj (hex)
    // console.log("Object: " + obj);
    var cnt = 0;
    for (var i in hexFiltered["_layers"][obj]["feature"]["properties"] ) {
        // print values out as 1 line (i)
        console.log("One line of values :" + hexFiltered["_layers"][obj]["feature"]["properties"][i]);
        // output = One line of values :,,,1,,,,1,1,,1

        // add values
        cnt = cnt + hexFiltered["_layers"][obj]["feature"]["properties"][i];
        console.log(cnt);
        // output = 0,,,1,,,,1,1,,1
    }
    // attach cnt to counts object
    counts += cnt;
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you are getting a string instead of a sum of the values of the arrays, then the solution is to iterate the array and add each element individually instead of trying to add the array to an integer.

If you add `0 + [1,2,3,4,5]` you will get `'01,2,3,4,5'`. What you should do is add another loop that iterates over the property that holds the array and add each element individually. An example of how to do this would be

```
    for (var j in hexFiltered["_layers"][obj]["feature"]["properties"]["NewCol"] ) {
        cnt += j
    }
```

This code should replace your second loop. I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do at the end of the code with `counts += cnt`, because counts is an object. If you just want a list of values then you should probably make counts an array (`counts = []`) so that you can do `counts.push cnt` instead of `counts += cnt`.

If this does not answer your question let me know and I will update the answer. Please be very specific with what you need if you need further help.